# Pivoting results in SQL Server

Tags: sql, merge, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ReferenceID  Field1 Field2 Field3
-----------  ------ ------ ------
111          Cat    Apple   Blue
111          Dog    Banana  Pink
111          Tiger  Pear    White
```

I am trying to get these to display in one row like

```
ReferenceID  Field1_1 Field2_1 Field3_1 Field1_2 Field2_2 Field3_2 Field1_3 Field2_3 Field3_3
-----------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------
111          Cat       Apple    Blue      Dog    Banana    Pink      Tiger  Pear    White
```

I've tried pivoting but I'm doing something wrong and can't get it to display the way I want.

Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT: I was using a query something like this:

EntityID is the one that repeats, RowNumberID is unique for every row.

```
SELECT A.EntityID,
A.[Sent for Technical Assessment],
A.[Return By Date],
A.[Date Assessment Returned to Board],
A.[Name of Assessor],
A.[RowNumberID],
B.EntityID,
B.[Sent for Technical Assessment],
B.[Return By Date],
B.[Date Assessment Returned to Board],
B.[Name of Assessor],
B.[RowNumberID],
C.EntityID,
C.[Sent for Technical Assessment],
C.[Return By Date],
C.[Date Assessment Returned to Board],
C.[Name of Assessor],
C.[RowNumberID]
FROM TEMP_TechAssessment A
INNER JOIN TEMP_TechAssessment B
ON A.EntityID= B.EntityID
INNER JOIN TEMP_TechAssessment C
ON A.EntityID=C.EntityID
WHERE A.RowNumberID != B.RowNumberID
AND B.RowNumberID != C.RowNumberID
AND C.RowNumberID != A.RowNumberID
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us the query that didn't quite work.

Comment: I tried a self join to see if that works, but couldn't get it to work the way I want.

Comment: So...where is the query????

Comment: Sorry, updated OP with query

Comment: Simple JOIN's won't pivot the result set. You need the `PIVOT` construct for that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The above query gives me the results of only the ones where the EntityID is repeated 3 times. I am trying to get my head around it, on how to proceed with the construction of the query but I seem to be lost.